# Is there a 'setvar' equivalent to 'setattr' in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

I'm trying to set a variable based on dynamic input from a dictionary. However, I'm not trying to set an attribute based on string input, I'm trying to set a variable. So, instead of:

`this.attribute = True`

I'm trying to dynamically set:

`this = True`

I can't create any conditional statements to predetermine what `this` might be, and it comes entirely from a string in a dictionary. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: the closest thing is `locals()['this'] = True;`, but it's not recommended... if you have control over it, change it to an object or dictionary.

Comment: You generally do *not* need to do this; you'd use a dictionary or list instead. Python's global module namespace is a dictionary too, reachable via `globals()`.

Comment: @CorleyBrigman: locals in a function are not mutable through `locals()` as that produces only a *one way reflection* of the local namespace; only `globals()` produces a direct reference to the global namespace. (`locals()` outside of a function gives you the same object `globals()` gives you).